# Mocking concrete classes without using a mocking framework

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, java-7

Let me preface this with - For the fear of introducing new dependencies (and beyond my comprehension), we don't use `mockito` or any 3rd party mocking frameworks.

We inject `ConcreteClass` as a dependency to our `class A` below. This dependency when `new`'d up does a `ServiceProvider` lookup. My thought during testing `method` below is to mock the lookup (we've an internal framework to do this) in `ConcreteClass` and return the required providers which are simply mock provider classes. This way when I create the `ConcreteClass` instance for testing I can inject my providers.

On the code review however, the suggestion is to create a mock subclass of the concrete class and inject that. Something like:

```
public class MockConcreteClass extends ConcreteClass 
{ 
  public void do() { } 
}
```

I'm thinking that this will undermine the ability to test in isolation since the mock is now directly dependent on the source code and I don't feel comfortable doing it. Is this the better way of doing it? Thoughts?

```
public class A
{
   private final ConcreteClass b;

   public A(ConcreteClass b)
   {
      this.b = b;
   }

   public void method()
   {
     b.do();
   }
}

public class ConcreteClass
{
   public ConcreteClass()
   {
     // Service Provider look up (can be mocked to return the desired providers)
   }

   public void do()
   {
   } 
}
```

Comment: The only improvement I can come up with is giving `ConcreteClass` an *interface* hat is expected by class `A`'s constructor. For what ever reason your company is rejecting mocking frameworks *coding against interfaces* is something they should  accept...

Comment: What is your opinion on extending the `ConcreteClass` and using that as a  mock? Is that a common practice?

Comment: It is "the last resort"...

Comment: Even if you extend `ConcreteClass` the constructor of `ConcreteClass` still will be called and you still will be looking up those non mock providers.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Do you think it's better than the solution I proposed because it uses dependency injection?

Comment: Insist on using a mocking framework. You can say Google is using mocking frameworks.

Comment: '"Do you think it's better than the solution I proposed because it uses dependency injection?"* **-** DI is the *essential precondition*. Without DI (which form ever) you cannot replace dependencies whith what *test doubles* ever neither, "generated" mocks nor "self coded"...

Comment: My approach doesn't really need DI but it is relying on the implementation detail of the constructor which could change. Sounds like extending the class is the only option if we don't choose to use an interface, interesting.